# Undefined reference to 'adjacency_array'

Tags: c, c99

When I try to compile my C program I get this error:

```
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./objects/linked_list.o:linked_list.c:(.rdata$.refptr.adjacency_array[.refptr.adjacency_array]+0x0): undefined reference to `adjacency_array'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The `adjacency_array` is an `extern Dynamic_Array *` (the `Dynamic_Array` type is defined in `data_types.h` which is included in all of my source files) I declared in `globals.h` (which is included in all of my source files as well) and I define it in `main.c`. The error is thrown when I try to call a function in `main.c` that was defined in `linked_list.c` but I don't understand why the `adjacency_array` variable isn't seen in `linked_list.c` since it's included in there.

`globals.h`:

```c
#pragma once

#include "data_types.h"

extern unsigned int id;
extern Dynamic_Array *adjacency_array;
```

`main.c`:

```c
//...

Dynamic_Array *adjacency_array = new_dynamic_array();

// ...
```

I'm not sure what else I should include in my question, but I will provide more information if needed.

Comment: How do you compile your code?

Comment: You are not defining adjacency_array at global scope.

Comment: Global variables are not recommended, don't use them.

Comment: Where are you defining the global `adjacency_array`?  You show a declaration in `main.c`, but since the intiializer appears to be calling a function, it is presumably a local variable to some function, not global.  Just create a global declaration for it, and get rid of any local declarations.  Or get rid of the global completely and only use a local.  You just need to be consistent.

Comment: This is the function I'm using to create the `adjacency_array`:
    Dynamic_Array *new_dynamic_array() {
        Dynamic_Array *new_array = (Dynamic_Array *) malloc(sizeof(Dynamic_Array));

        new_array->size = 0;
        new_array->array = (struct Linked_List **) malloc(new_array->size * sizeof(struct Linked_List **));

        return new_array;
    }

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve].

Comment: @szmoli You don't seem to be making the distinction between a variable definition and a variable assignment.  A variable definition defines the variable (it declares it, and also specifies storage for it).  That is independent of initializing its value.  You have not defined your global variable.  That is why the linker is giving you an error.  It doesn't exist.  So, define it.  *Then* you can worry about initializing its value.  Maybe consult a tutorial, and look at how to declare and define global variables?

Comment: @TomKarzes thank you. I totally overlooked this but now that I defined it everything works.